# How do you protect your API key in your tests when you publish a gem with tests?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using rspec in my test and i would like to protect my API key it when i publish my gem on github. 
What are the best practices to do that? should i use VCR and then remove my key from the git log?

Comment: Why not use a fake key in your tests? Furthermore if your tests need to use a web API service, you should be mocking the http requests and responses to those services. An API key should be something you can fake in a test. If you can't then you need to re-architect your gem so that you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, here are three approaches I have used in the past in similar situations. Which you choose will depend on the details your particular situation.

- Test user supplies API key

If your test suite requires, or at least prefers, actual API calls with an actual API key, you can have the caller of the tests supply the credentials when running the tests.

Two most common ways of doing this are:

- File in project with well-known name which is not checked into version control. Include an example with fake credentials, which is checked into version control, along with instructions for users to supply their real credentials into the real file before calling test suite.
- Read from environment variables. Include instructions for users to set appropriate environment variables before calling test suite.

Otherwise,

- Mock out the API

This can be the VCR approach you described. This could also be patching the API call to return some fake results.

- Test your domain-specific code separate from the API interaction

Assume the API and the API client behave how you expect. Then, factor out the parts of your code which construct the API input and process the API output. Test properties of your input generated. Test behavior of output processor with known or fake output.

**Finally, a warning:**

**If you have ever committed your API key to version control, it will visible in the history. If you have ever pushed to a public hosting service, it will have been exposed to the Internet, most notably, it will have been exposed to specialized bots which scrape newly-pushed commits for sensitive credentials. If this is you, change your credentials now!**

I can't find the original blog post at the moment, but there was at least one report of someone accidentally pushing their AWS credentials to GitHub. They subsequently woke up to a several thousand dollar bill.